# Different paths to include a file

Tags: php

I have the following structure of my project (watch image). I need include menu.php in each file but index.php need a different path:

[image]

```
index.php: include('../contenido/menu.php');
agregar.php: include('../../contenido/menu.php');
```

How can I solve that issue? I do not use a framework.

Answer (score 1):

Set the include path based on the file in question.

You can add a relative path using the [`__DIR__` magic constant](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php).

For example, in `index.php`...

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, [
    __DIR__ . '/../contenido',
    get_include_path()
]));
```

and in your `vistas/productos` scripts...

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, [
    __DIR__ . '/../../contenido',
    get_include_path()
]));
```

---

Then, it doesn't matter where you are, you can simply add

```
include 'menu.html';
```